# Error when installing Office 2010: "setup cannot find the required setup controller file"

Tags: windows, microsoft-office

I uninstalled Office 2007 from my old laptop through the control panel. When I tried to install Office 2010, it gives an error "setup cannot find the required setup controller file".

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and went searching all over the internet before I realized what was actually happening.

I downloaded an ISO file from microsoft, opened it and tried to run the setup.exe from there, which *DOESN'T WORK*.

If you tried to do this, then that is likely your problem.  You need to mount the ISO file first -- there are a bunch of free programs that do this.  Virtual Clone Drive and PowerISO are 2.  When you mount the ISO as a disc using one of these programs, the set up will run.

Comment: Using Parallels on OSX, I mounted the image in OSX. That didn't work. I had to mount the iso in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this forum thread: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sr/officesetupdeploy/thread/0ed769de-ced8-4408-8bdb-96af5d9341cc

Some suggestions from the thread:

1. Try to completely uninstall Office programs and then install Office 2010 again. To uninstall, follow the steps in this KB article: How do I uninstall Office 2003, Office 2007 or Office 2010 suites if I cannot uninstall it from Control Panel http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301
2. "I was getting this error when trying to depoly via startup script in group policy.  The problem was that Authenticated Users needed read rights to the install directory.  Not sure if this applies in your situation but make sure the account your installing with has rights to the install directory."
3. "I have seen this error because of running system restore does not bring back certain "xml" files from your  setup controller directory. The fix is to re-run Office setup from your disk or web downloadable. You can find setup logs by clicking the start "or perl" button -> typing '%temp%' (without the ' marks) and then look for setupexe(#####).log files. If you are still having trouble you can email me at micrey [at] microsoft [dot] com."

Please expand on your answer if none of this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Firefox as the default web browser? If "Yes", change the default browser to Internet Explorer while doing the installation.

This is the fix suggested by Microsoft and the fix used a few minutes ago. Office 2010 loaded OK on 2 machines which were using Intenet Explorer as default and failed to load on the Firefox default browser machine.

Comment: Care to link to where MS say this?

Answer (score 0):

- Open the "rar" project with WinRAR, not with 7zip
- Go to admin directory
- Go to "de-de"
- You will see all the Office features e.g `word14.opal`, `visio14.opal` etc.
- Extract each and every feature
- Go to setup again. There will be no error this time.

Answer (score 0):

1. First mount the disk image with the help of software like daemon tools.
2. Copy the content and paste it somewhere in your file system like D drive
3. Now run the set up, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a zip file then unzip the package on the drive you have installed windows. For ex: if you have windows on c drive then un pack the installation package on c drive and then run the setup. It will run without any hassle.

Answer (score -2):

I also had the similar problem. I got winrar instead on 7zip and mounted the iso file. The setup file ran successfully without any error.